# Why are JavaScript files read from an external URL?

Tags: theming, javascript, files

Drupal adds the following markup to pages.

```
<html class="js" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#" xmlns:skos="http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#" xmlns:sioct="http://rdfs.org/sioc/types#" xmlns:sioc="http://rdfs.org/sioc/ns#" xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#" xmlns:foaf="http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/terms/" xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/" dir="rtl" version="XHTML+RDFa 1.0" xml:lang="fa" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

I need to remove it and force my site not to read from an external URL.

How can I achieve this? Is it really bad, or doesn't it need to be changed?

Answer (score 3):

You're confusing the attributes on that tag.

- `class="js"` is a class name, it has nothing to do with loading javascript from external sources. It's simply added to the tag by javascript when the page loads so that any process (css usually) that needs to know about it can easily tell whether javascript is enabled or not.
- The `xml:*` attributes are required to identify the document as XHTML. They're not related to javascript in any way.

There's no need to change anything, unless you want to get a bit more up-to-date and install a theme that produces an HTML5 document.

Answer (score 0):

That line isn't loading any Javascript file from an external URL. It simply defines the document type as [XHTML+RDFa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XHTML%2BRDFa) (an extended version of the [XHTML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XHTML) markup language that supports [RDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Description_Framework)), the [XML namespaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace) used in the document, and a [CSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets) class used for the `<html>` tag.
Actually, nothing is loaded from those URLs, which are simply used as namespace names.

To answer the question, nothing needs to be removed. Quite the opposite, the attributes of the `<html>` tag are necessary for the browsers to correctly identify the document type as XHTML, which the document type used from Drupal 7 for the HTML pages it outputs.